# How can follow the Hero with endless?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I want to follow the Hero with endless.   I have using the following code with limit.  It is limited area to follow the Hero.

Here is the coding:

```
 CCSize size = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
 CCRect rect = CCRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
 this->runAction(CCFollow::create(playerSprite, rect));
```

My game logic -  Hero is moving continuously with no boundary.

How can hero follow the object with endless?

Any idea should help me a lot.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried with CCRepeatForeever action?

Comment: I want CCFollow.    It needs limited boundary as a argument.  How will i do using CCRepeatForeever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
 this->runAction(CCFollow::create(playerSprite));
```